# Locating string literals in C++ source with regex, but not includes?

Tags: regex, qt, internationalization, qt-creator

I want to introduce i18n in an existing application. As a first step, I need to replace the string literals with `tr("something")`.

I have created the following regex to extract the strings:

```
(?<!#include)"([^"\\]|\\.)*"
```

However, this does not work. Without the negative lookbehind, it does match strings correctly, but also quoted includes which I want to avoid. I'm not quite familiar with negative lookbehinds, I just looked them up [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Example:

```
#include "hello.h"                           // should NOT match "\"hello.h\""
printf("Hello");                             // should match "\"Hello\""
cout << "hello" << "hello" << "hello";       // should match each three "\"hello\""'s
```

How can I do this correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is my solution (sort of):

First, I could not do it in Qt Creator, its regex capabilities seem to be not so good at the moment. So I used vim.

I opened all the affected files as vim buffers, then recorded the following macro:

```
qa:%s/\v(#include\s+)@<!"([^"]*)"/tr(\0)/g<CR>:bn<CR>q
```

This does the following:

```
qa                                       // start recording into register "a"
%s/\v(#include\s+)@<!"([^"]*)"/tr(\0)/g  // search and replace as specified
<CR>                                     // (hit enter)
:bn                                      // jump to the next buffer
<CR>                                     // (hit enter)
q                                        // end recording macro
```

The regex is vim-regex with \v that makes more natural (less escaping). In short, it uses a negative lookbehind as I originally wanted, with a slightly different syntax.

Now, I only had to run this macro for as many buffers I had open (in command mode):

```
78@a
```

The problem (and this is why it's only a "sort of" solution) is that whenever vim encounters a buffer where the regex fails (i.e. no string literals in the file) it stops repeating the macro. I couldn't find out how to fix that. Fortunately I had only a few files like that, so I could get away with manually re-running the above command to start repeating the macro again.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this one

```
(?<!#include\s)"(?:\\\"|[^"\n])*?"
```

It works directly(without groups). It also supports escaped quotes in strings. The only constraint here is **one space between #include and file name**. This is because QTcreator doesnt support quantifiers in negative lookbehind.

Ill try to fix it. But not sure that ill succeed.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work either. (not even without the lookbehind part)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

`(?!^#include).*?(\"[^\"]+?\").*?`

The strings in quotes are captured by the group.

In java:

```
    String s = "(?!^#include).*?(\"[^\"]+?\").*?";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(s);

    System.out.println(p.matcher("#include \"hello.h\" ").matches());
    System.out.println(p.matcher("printf(\"Hello\"); ").matches());
    System.out.println(p.matcher("cout << \"hello\" << \"hello\" << \"hello\"; ").matches());
```

Comment: It does not work for me. In Qt Creator, it matches nothing, while in regexpal.com it matches almost everything.